# Ошибка fbd python linux TypeError: isinstance()

Tags: python, firebird

Подскажите в чем заключается проблема, на windows данный код запускается и выполняется без всяких проблем а на linux (centos stream) в конце выполнения скрипта когда tuple заканчивается выдаётся ошибка

Exception ignored in: <bound method Cursor.**del** of <fdb.fbcore.Cursor object at0x7fbc98147fd0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 3932, in **del**
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 3643, in close
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 481, in is_dead_proxy
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: В функцию isinstance вторым аргументом передаётся неправильный тип данных. Вместо класса что-то ещё. А какой код-то? Может скинете сам код программы, где возникает ошибка?

Comment: Извините сам код скинуть не могу, Суть данного кода опрос идёт через for баз данных, реквизиты берутся из бд pg, самое что странное когда tuple кончается выдаётся данная ошибка, хотя в con fbd уже не чего не передаётся.

Comment: В исходниках такая строка: `return isinstance(obj, weakref.ProxyType) and not dir(obj)`, и вроде `weakref.ProxyType` в питоне 3.6 уже есть, непонятно, почему такая ошибка. Если только баг какой-то в 3.6, который потом поправили.

Comment: Исходник https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/fdb/blob/master/fdb/fbcore.py

Comment: А на Windows у вас та же версия Python и этой библиотеки?

Comment: Да, версия одинаковая.

Comment: Единственная разница в том что на windows версия python "Python 3.8.6" а на linux Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даная проблема решилась только при переходе с python3.6.8 на версию Python 3.8.8 и установки используемых библиотек для 3.8

Comment: Ну, видимо, в Python 3.6 всё же есть какой-то баг с `isinstance` и `weakref.ProxyType`

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь!